# Why aren't Shiva Purana and Vishnu Purana updated?

Tags: shiva-purana, vishnu-purana

The **Shiva Purana** and **Vishnu Purana** contains some deeds of the Lord Shiva and Lord Vishnu respectively which had happened. Both Lord Shiva and Lord Vishnu exist even today, now they might be doing some deeds.

Now why aren't the current deeds of Lord Shiva and Lord Vishnu written? To be more precise, why aren't **Shiva Purana** and **Vishnu Purana** updated with the latest deeds of the Lord Shiva and Lord Vishnu?

For example, Lord Shiva's marriage with Goddess Parvathi, the birth of Lord Karthikeya, Lord Ganesha. In a similar way, what is currently going on now?

Is any rishi writing them currently? Are they updated every yuga with the latest deeds? What is current status of Lord Shiva and Lord Vishnu?

Comment: great question! it is highly unlikely that shiva purana or vishnu purana will be updated, simply because if they are, then it will be dismissed as interpolation!

Comment: @Sai I mean adding more deeds which they are doing now, not modifying the previous deeds (which of course, cannot be done since it is happened).

Comment: There are many who believe that some Parvas and texts in certain Puranas are questionable, simply because they were later additions. addition now would only make people believe 'this was a later addition to the Shiva purana, so its authenticity is not sure!' see this book where it says "So, though many people look to the Bhavishya Purana for its predictions of the future, it is not considered fully dependable because of the additions and deletions." The Heart of Hinduism: The Eastern Path to Freedom, Empowerment and Illumination By Stephen Knapp. That's why I dont see it happening

Comment: However there are many books which describe the Leelas of Shiva and God in general (like Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, Autobiography of a Yogi, Shri Sai Satcharitha, Sathyam Sivam Sundaram, Sri Ramana Leela, Sri Great Chaitanya Charitamrita, ) all these are in some way current 'deeds' of God you can say. Thus they can be counted, although not officially, as the current leelas of Bhagavan

Comment: @Sai Regardless of their authenticity, isn't something going on currently? What is Lord Shiva currently now? What about Lord Vishnu?

Comment: yes definitely they are doing things currently! however just like in the time of Rama and Krishna, not everyone can believe it. For example, how many would believe me if I said that Sri Ramanujacharya is an incarnation now? Perhaps the Vaishnavas. How many would believe me if I said that Chaitanya Mahaprabhu was an incarnation of Sri Krishna? the gaudiya vaishnavas? How many would belive me if I said Sai Baba is an incarnation of Lord Shiva? The Sai Baba devotees? The same goes for Ramakrishna, Sathya Sai Baba, Ramana Maharishi, Adi Shankaracharya. These are all the current leelas of God!

Comment: Who do you think should update it? And what qualifications should they have? Should the updater not be a seer of Vyasa's stature? When the time is right, the updated versions will be made available to mankind. You must remember that time and space are not limited to earth and our calendar. Asking questions just to appear smart will not lead us anywhere.

Comment: what i think we read in the scriptures is a very brief history of very long time span, If we go inside we find, that we have not even lived half of historical time span, as is been quoted in the scriptures. So we can presume current is not an extremist time to review the scriptures, as is written they are reviewed every dwapar yuga.

Comment: @Sai "Apprenticed to a Himalayan Master" by Sri M is also a very good autobiography.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Thanks for that reference! I do love autobiographies.

Answer (score 1):

Namasthe.  From an English translation of [Devi Bhagavatam](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/index.htm) I read a while back....
In every Manvantara, before the beginning of Kali yuga (at end of Dvâpara Yuga), Sri Maha Vishnu takes the avatar of Veda Vyasa.   Since, the people in Kali Yuga do not have the patience or longivity, etc to realize God, he simplifies the sacred texts by dividing the (one) Veda into four parts and expounding the Purânas duly to preserve the religion. 
In other words, these texts are written at a specific point in the yuga cycle and then re-written.   So I assume updates do happen.

On a philosphical note (personal comment), Puranas which document the deeds of Gods should be interpreted with help of a learned person.  So it is not the comprehensiveness of all the deeds of God, but rather the divinty of those deeds which need to be internalized and meditated on and dovetailed with Yogic (Bhagavad Gita) way of living.  So if the deeds are enough to move your heart to love God, then I feel there is no need to keep appending.